# Join by location QGIS and PostGIS -> different results

Tags: qgis, postgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I get different results, performing a spatial join with PostGIS and QGIS.
The data can be downloaded [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ae25571c60d94ce5b7fcbf74e27c00e0).

I try to join `vg2500_krs` (402 rows) with `vg2500_bld` (16 rows). I am interested in writing the information from `vg2500_bld` into `vg2500_krs`, keeping all records from `vg2500_krs`.
In QGIS I select `Vector - Data Management Tools - Join Attributes by Location`. The resulting shapefile has 402 rows, as expected.

However, when I try to do this with PostGIS, I get a shapefile with 638 rows.

This is the query I use:

```
CREATE TABLE krs_bld AS
SELECT k.gen, k.rs, k.geom, b.name_bld
FROM vg2500_krs k
LEFT OUTER JOIN vg2500_bld b
ON ST_Intersects(k.geom, b.geom) AND NOT ST_Touches(k.geom, b.geom);
```

Further, when I look at the Shapefile created by PostGIS in QGIS, especially at the duplicated rows, they "do not exists". When I highlight them and "Zoom to selected Feature", there is nothing highlighted in the mapview. It is as if nothing was selected. But, when I calculate the area for the rows, it does not result in 0. 
Where does this behavior come from?

Comment: For the on statement you could try: ON ST_Intersects(ST_Centroid(k.geom), b.geom)

Comment: @Vesanto that does not explain, why it does not "respect" the `ST_Touches`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the ST_Touches without impacting the results of the SQL query.

`AND NOT ST_Touches(k.geom, b.geom);`

The reason for this that ST_Touches and PostGIS in general is really precise. To you it looks like the two datasets line up perfectly. But they do not.

If you really zoom in on the two files at the boundaries:

[image]

They do not line up. ST_Touches works on a perfect touch, this is a precision you cannot achieve in QGIS or ArcGIS, you would need a true topological GIS (like GRASS).

So the workaround, and how QGIS is probably already doing it, is to use the centroids for the intersection. Or even better a point on surface.

So if you modify the query to:

```
CREATE TABLE krs_bld AS
SELECT k.gen, k.rs, k.geom, b.name_bld
FROM vg2500_krs k
LEFT OUTER JOIN vg2500_bld b
ON ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(k.geom), b.geom);
```

You should get the results you desire.

You can read about a similar issue [here](http://gisforthought.com/centroid-within-selection-in-qgis/), and why ST_Centroid might not work either.

Comment: Oh wow. That is something I did not know! Thanks a lot for pointing that one out. You taught me something